# How to remove tag cloud from taxonomy admin edit page?

Tags: customization, tags, functions

On the page where one adds/removes/modifies taxonomies, what would I need to add to my functions.php file to remove the tag cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what filter you would add to your functions.php, but I believe you could get rid of the tag cloud with the Adminimize plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, if you want to remove it for all taxonomy pages

```
add_filter( 'wp_tag_cloud', 'remove_tag_cloud', 10, 2 );

function remove_tag_cloud ( $return, $args )
{
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Low, just used your code and it worked brilliantly.

I have not tested it, but if you wish to only do it on some taxonomy types, I guess you could use the global $pagenow to check which page you are on.

Comment: I believe this answer has more potential for customization.